# How to customize shared content of my website on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

Every time I copy a link from popular news channels like TNW, Engadget, etc. I have a very nice sharing view (with a thumbnail that I may select, a bold title, and a short summary).
When I do the same with an article from my website, it does not look as nice.
How can I customize how my Facebook share will look?

Answer (score 2):

You need to embed the Open Graph (OG) meta tags into your page to give the facebook page scraper a chance

http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

---

EDIT

the [facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) should help interpret what is being read